# Transfering values from an object in a ArrayList to an array sudoku board

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, printing, sudoku

I will explain you my problem: I need to fill this grid:

```
static int board[][]=new int[][]
           {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
```

But I want to be able to transfert the values inside my arraylist objet (ligne,colone,valeur):

```
Case case1=new Case(ligne, colone, valeur);
monArrayCase.add(case1);
```

I've already made a scanner and a print to verify that my arraylist number are added and that working...

My main problem is that I printing this :

```
System.out.println(Sudoku.board[ligne-1][colone-1]=valeur);
```

I can add number but I can't delete them...Maybe cause I am doing it in the array...Is there an way to print the value from my arraylist object on the grill?Thank in advance.

Comment: Yeah it is...Why are you asking?

Comment: to add the tag :-) thx

Comment: ok..Sorry didn't thought about that..Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you have the following setup already:

- You have some `ArrayList<Case>` called `monArrayCase` which contains
- up to 81 `Case`s, where each `Case` consists of a row (`ligne`), column (`cologne`), and value (`valeur`) each of which ranges between 1 and 9 (hence the 0-indexing adjustment in the `println` statement)

With this, you want to populate your 2D array.
*if i got it backward, skip to the end*

Write a few methods to manipulate cells in the board:

```
static void insertCaseToBoard(Case case) {
    Sudoku.board[case.ligne-1][case.colone-1] = case.valeur;
}

static void removeCaseFromBoard(int ligne, int colone) {
    Sudoku.board[ligne-1][colone-1] = 0;
}

static void clearBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            Sudoku.board[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And one to iterate through the `ArrayList<Case>` and insert all the values:

```
static void fillBoard(ArrayList<Case> inArray) {
    clearBoard();
    for (Case aCase in inArray) {
        insertCaseToBoard(aCase);
    }
}
```

If you want to populate the `ArrayList<Case>` with the board already set, do something simpler:

```
static ArrayList<Case> listFromBoard() {
    ArrayList<Case> myList = new ArrayList<Case>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            int valeur = Sudoku.board[i][j];
            if (valuer != 0) myList.add(new Case(i+1,j+1,valeur);
        }
    }
}
```